# inserting element into a list, if condition is met with C#

Tags: c#, list

**How to insert some number into the middle of the list, if there is no such number present?**

In the example below I'm trying to insert number 4

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };
        int must_enter = 4;
        if (!list1.Contains(must_enter))
        {
            list1.Add(must_enter);
        }
```

As the result number will be entered at the end of the list, but I want it **right after 3 (before 5)**.

please note that due to project's specifics I can't use sorted list, but all numbers in the list are **guaranteed** to be in ascending order (0,2,6,9,10,...)

**EDIT:** I knew about an error and that's what I did:

```
        List<int> list0 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };
        int must_enter = 7;
        if (!list0.Contains(must_enter))
        {
            if (must_enter < list0.Max())
            {
                int result = list0.FindIndex(item => item > must_enter || must_enter > list0.Max());
                list0.Insert(result, must_enter);
            }
            else
            {
                list0.Add(must_enter);
            }

        }
```

edit2: anyway I've switched to BinarySearch method due to several factors. Everyone thanks for your help!

Comment: you have accepted wrong solution check @EsotericScreenName comment after the answer.....its gives you ans error ....

Comment: just to note the accepted answer still not answering what you need its just searching and inserting its not looping for each missing element.................so you need to modify your code according to that .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int index = list1.BinarySearch(must_enter);
if (index < 0)
 list1.Insert(~index, must_enter);
```

This way you will keep the list sorted with the best possible performance.

Comment: even though previous method worked fine for me, I must admit that your solution is fast and very simple.. definitely the best answer

Comment: -1 - just to note the answer still not answering what OP need its just searching and inserting its not looping for each missing element.................so you need to modify your code according to that ..... what for the list like {0,2,6,9,10} and need to insert  1,3,4,5 in that

Comment: no it's ok, I don't need to know what's missing. There is only ONE number that I need to find and insert if necessary, every other number besides it is irrelevant, so the answer fully answers my question.. sorry for misunderstanding, if anything

Comment: @Alex - if its like that than you just need is Inset method nothing else .....which i alreayd suggested first and people downvoted without any reason

Comment: @Casperah seems to have downvoted 3 answers, without any reason. So it's  a good practise downvote and comment with a **good reason**. It seems that he wants to highlight his answer. Yes it's a great answer, but still don't understand why he behaves in this way.

Comment: I do not downvote good answers, and I made some comments about why I downvoted them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
list1.Add(must_enter);
```

And then order the list:

```
list1 = list1.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
```

The result will be:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

**EDIT:**

Or use an extesion method:

```
static class Utility
{
     public static void InsertElement(this List<int> list, int n)
     {
         if(!list.Contains(n))
         {     
             for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
             {
                  if(list[i] > n)
                  {
                     list.Insert(i-1, n);
                     break;
                  }

                  if(i == list.Count - 1)
                     list.Add(n);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

And then:

```
list1.InsertElement(must_enter);
```

Comment: I don't think OP's `project's specifics` would allow this :)

Comment: I think that list1.Sort() will do the job faster, but it will still lack performance.

Comment: He don't want to use a sorted list.

Comment: +1 - most of the people downvoting so that their answer get more highlited so no worries your answer it meeting requirement

Comment: thanks...and thanks for higliting its alredy big mess over here i m leaving this question as of now

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
list1.Insert(index, must_enter);
```

To insert an element at a specific index rather than at the end of the list.

You'll have to find the index to insert at first which is easily done with a binary search. Start with the value in the middle of the list and compare it to your number to insert. If it's greater, search the lower half of the list, if it's more, search the upper half of the list. Repeat the process, dividing the list in half each time until you find the spot where the item before is less than the one you are inserting and the item after is more than the one you are inserting. (edit: of course, if you list is always very small, it's probably less hassle just to iterate through the list from the beginning to find the right spot!)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.Insert(4, 4)
```

[**`List<T>.Insert Method`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) - Inserts an element into the List at the specified index.

**Quick Note**-
the Insert instance method on the List type does not have good performance in many cases. because for Insert, list has to adjust the following elements.

here is the original post from where i got this answer try it out may help you : [Finding best position for element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748596/finding-best-position-for-element-in-list)

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{0,2,6,9,10};
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
   int index = list.BinarySearch(i);
   if( i < 0)
   {
    int insertIndex = ~index; 
    list.Insert(insertIndex, i);
   }
}
```

just for one missing element as op needs

```
   int index = list.BinarySearch(4);
   if( index < 0)
   {
    int insertIndex = ~index; 
    list.Insert(insertIndex, 4);
   }
```

or

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 0,2,6,9,10 };
int must_enter = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
     if (!list1.Contains(i))
     {
         list1.Insert(i , i);
     }
}
```

just for one element as op needs

```
     if (!list1.Contains(4))
     {
         list1.Insert(4 , 4);
     }
```

Comment: For list `(0,2,6,9,10,...)` ?

Comment: @Casperah - its not totally incorrect ... as he posted question such like that i proposed op to use insert method and than added other thing as he added some clear thought...i hope you like to consider this and remove your downvote

Comment: @Casperah - check my update i proposed solution of binarysearch for this and than insert element i hope its not incorrect

Comment: @sarwar026 - i edited my answer as added binarysearch for inserting element hope you interested in that and may remove your downvote

Comment: I have checked your updates, are you sure this is your solution to the problem?

Comment: @L.B - check my comment for downvoting if he edit the answer i remove my downvote for sure....check your first comment in my answer will the accepted answer work for that ......

Comment: @L.B - also check alex comment.....he fail to mention what he need ...any way i m removing my downvote because the answer satisfy his need..

Comment: Wow what people do for some measley stackoverflow points?  What will those points buy you folks?

Comment: ok, just to clarify things here. Guys lets stay polite. Once this answer was given - this solutions was static, it was no good for anything other than number 4. Although I have to admit that after countless edits it sure is working as it should be, but due to the fact that Casperah was actually the first to write BinarySearch method, I can't approve this answer as "first and unique". my sole opinion.

Comment: @JonH - i dont want point for the answer but the whoever ask question must be clear with the question and go for proper answer thats it ....no point issue in that ...i dont go for points as i upvoted all answer in this question

Comment: @Pranay +1 repair to downvote of some people, but not only, nice answer :)

Comment: @Alex - i just want to say ask proper question here people are downvoting without any reason now just to highlight there answer ....the other anwswer are not wrong the also work for you .....that doent mean people downvote it ...

Comment: Pranay Rane Why are you downvoting good answers and upvoting bad answers?

Comment: @Casperah- that what you did not me ..........anyway i upvoted your answer also and removed my downvote...just for your info when he ask question my answer is correct as per what he ask and the my answer is downvoted without any reason....and i upvoted most of the answer in this question so plz dont blame on me for such silly reasonss.........i hope you dont mind it

Comment: @PranayRana: I didn't downvote, only want to say that your first one will not work with L.B.'s example.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };
int must_enter = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
     if (must_enter >= list1[i])
     {
         list1.Insert(i + 1, must_enter);
     }
}
```

Edit: I like sarwar026, implementation better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };
    int must_enter = 4;
    if (!list1.Contains(must_enter))
    {
        int result = list.FindIndex(item => item > must_enter);
        if(result!=-1)
            list1.Insert(result, must_enter);
        else  // must_enter is not found
        {
            if(must_enter > list.Max()) // must_enter > max value of list
                list1.Add(must_enter);
            else if(must_enter < list.Min())  // must_enter < min value of list
                list1.Insert(0, must_enter);
        }
    }
```

First, find the index of the number which is greater than **must_enter**(4) and then insert the **must_enter** to that position

Comment: I think it has a serious performance issue. Looping through the entire collection twice to add a single integer. O(2*n)

Comment: -1: In your example, if `must_enter` > 6, your code throws an exception, as `FindIndex` returns -1.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Thanks. I have update my code. Hopefully, it will work now perfectly.

Comment: @sarwar026: Code is still broken. Inside your else block you've switched the greater than / less than signs, and you're still trying to insert a record at index -1.

Comment: @Casperah: Inserting into the middle of a list is `O(N)` already, this is no worse.

Comment: hi buddy just to say for this comment of your on my answer "It will not work for L.B example for sure" - L.B is not posted the question i asnwer the question that asked by Alex op of the answer.... next time make sure that who is asking the question before downvoting some one answer .........

Comment: @PranayRana: I didn't downvote, only want to say that your first one will not work with L.B.'s example.

Comment: @PranayRana: Also, the question who asked this, also tell something like **please note that due to project's specifics I can't use sorted list, but all numbers in the list are guaranteed to be in ascending order (0,2,6,9,10,...)**. So, i just comment that nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!list1.Contains(must_enter))
{
    SortedSet<int> sorted = new SortedSet<int>( list1 );
    sorted.Add( must_enter );
    list1 = sorted.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Looping through the entire collection, sorting it once more and adding the new value and then converting it back to a list. I do not think it is the best way to do this simple task.

Comment: @Casperah. I got curious, so I benchmarked my solution against yours. It turns out that your solution is about 200% quicker.

Comment: Great, I like the fact that you actually tested it, I will revard you by undoing my downvote.